# How do I remove git with apple version?

Tags: git

I am currently having a problem to install git that is without the apple version. This is what is currently shown on my terminal.

[image]

Comment: what does `which git` print? Also, what method are you using to install git?

Comment: "_A macOS Git installer is maintained and available for download at the Git website, at https://git-scm.com/download/mac._"

Comment: this is what it says: /usr/bin/git when i print which git

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` has `/usr/local/bin` *after* `/usr/bin`, so you will get `/usr/bin/git` in preference to `/usr/local/bin/git` when both are installed.  You can explicitly run `/usr/local/bin/git`, or `/usr/bin/git`, to pick one of the two for one particular command.  It's generally inadvisable to uninstall system-provided versions of software, but if you *change* your `PATH` setting to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, running `git` will get you the locally-installed version instead.